# PostgreSQL, Change values after a limit is reached

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I have the following tables

Discounts orders

```
id | employee |
---|----------|
 1 |1         |
 2 |2         |
 3 |1         |
 4 |3         |
 5 |3         |
 6 |1         |
 7 |1         |
 8 |1         |
 9 |1         |
```

Somewhere else I have the employee salary.

What I want to do is the following.

If the employee exist on the discounts orders table do the following:

-> 1 row on the "discounts orders table" Discount the 30% from the salary value and insert 1 row on "table X" with the amount of the employee_id and discount value.

-> 2 rows on the "discounts orders table" Discount the 30% from the salary value and insert 2 row on "table X" with the amount of the employee_id and discount value.

-> 3 rows on the "discounts orders table" Discount the 30% from the salary value and insert 3 row on "table X" with the amount of the employee_id and discount value.

-> 4 rows on the "discounts orders table" Discount the 30% from the salary value and insert 3 row on "table X" with the amount of the employee_id and discount value (3 times 30% makes 90% of salary) The 4th inserted row should be ony for 10% (To reach 100% of the salary)

-> >4 rows on the "discounts orders table" make the process for the case above and ignore the rest. (because you can't discount more than the 100% of salary)

If employee #1 earn $1000 and have 10 rows on the "discounts orders table"
the X table should look like this

```
id | employee | discount_value | discounts_orders_id
---|----------|----------------|--------------------
1  | 1        | 300            | 1
2  | 1        | 300            | 3
3  | 1        | 300            | 6
4  | 1        | 100            | 7
```

EDITED:

I found a temporal solution.

```
insert into "table x" ....
select (employee_salary * 0.30) from employee
inner join discounts_orders ....
limit 4
```

I insert 4 rows with (salary * 0.30) then I update 1 row with (salary * 0.10)

Comment: Please show us what code you've tried so far!

Comment: Hi Alex, I updated the post, you can see a temporal solution, I bet there's a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to calculate the amount of entries with a subquery and then deciding the factor with a CASE WHEN like this:

```
insert into "table x" ....
select (employee_salary * 
  (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM discounts_orders as dior
             WHERE dior.employee=employee.id 
                  AND dior.id<=discounts_orders.id) < 4 
       THEN 0.30
       ELSE 0.10
       END)) from employee
inner join discounts_orders ....
limit 4
```